# How to configure NGINX to Redirect Traffic to Different Ports if Interface has Multiple IP Addresses

Tags: ubuntu, networking, nginx, port-forwarding, reverse-proxy

An Ubuntu 20.04 machine with a single network interface is given 3 IP addresses. We want to run several instances of a program that listens to a specific port and have one instance listening to each of the 3 IP addresses.

```
instance1  <==>  listening on localhost:8000  <===>  network interface 1 (IP addr: 10.0.0.10)
instance2  <==>  listening on localhost:8001  <===>  network interface 1 (IP addr: 10.0.0.11)
instance3  <==>  listening on localhost:8002  <===>  network interface 1 (IP addr: 10.0.0.12)
```

Is it possible to configure NGINX to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set as many virtual servers as you want in nginx.conf as long as you follow the syntax to describe them. And you do not need to manually tell nginx to set up 3 processes to do so, it will handle that on its own.

Answer (score 0):

to do this you need to add  ip address in the listen statement of nginx conf  ... like so

```
listen 10.0.0.10:8000;
```